# How can I trigger a model observer with an ajax call?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have created a model observer according to the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers)

Which successfully creates the `UserObserver.php` file in my `Observers` directory.

In my `created` method, to test if things were working I was just logging to [debugbar](

```
public function created(User $user)
{
    Debugbar::info('User created!');
}
```

I'm using an ajax call to create a user - and when the user is successfully created, I'm not seeing anything show in the messages tab of the debugbar.

I have registered the observer in my `AppServiceProvider` file:

```
public function boot()
{
    User::observe(UserObserver::class);
}
```

I've also tried putting this in my `User` model:

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'created' => UserObserver::class,
    'deleted' => UserObserver::class,
];
```

Still no luck.

Is there a different method to try because the request is ajax?
Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: try writing to a log file and see if you get anything. For it to work with the debugbar it would have to have a websocket connection open or do some polling to get the data in real time.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan - I've tried using `Log::info('User created!');` Instead of the Debugbar, and not seeing anything show in `storage/logs/`

Comment: Can you post your User model code? If you have added a `__construct()` or `boot()` method, it's possible you've disrupted the typical event firing cycle.

Comment: I don't have a `__construct()` or a `boot()` method in my model. Is that something I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Bryan and Aken - I very much appreciate the time you took to help.

Here is what I ended up with in hopes that it will help someone else.

`User.php` (model)

```
/**
 * The event map for the model.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'created' => UserCreated::class,
];

...
```

Then, going through [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events#generating-events-and-listeners) to generate an event/listener I created (the system created) a `Users` directory. Within that is a file called `UserCreated.php`

`EventServiceProvider.php`

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
    UserCreated::class => [
        CreateDefaultReportConfiguration::class,
      ],
    ];
],
```

From there a `Listeners` directory was created with a file called, `CreateDefaultReportConfiguration.php`

```
...

/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  UserCreated $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(UserCreated $event)
{
    Log::info('UserCreated Listener');
}
```

Now in my `/storage/logs/` directory:

```
local.INFO: UserCreated Listener
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept your own answer so it can help others.